# How do I go from BVH to a working F-Curve?

Tags: animation, bones, fcurves

I found a BVH I want to use by first checking the motion in BVH Hacker, I import it into Blender, delete the rig the importing generated, select my character, then choose the BVH from the F-Curves list to apply it to my character, only the hip translates.

My character, I renamed all the bones to the corresponding bone names in the BVH file, I imagined that would make it work, but no. As I select my character's bones it corresponds in the action editor highlighting Location and Euler so why is it not animating my character?

Also, my character does not have any IK or any kind of bone controls or contstraints.

[blend and bvh zip](http://www.filedropper.com/bvhtest)

Comment: Please share the files, and tell us which version of Blender you're using.

Comment: Could you post a link to the bvh file please. Often it is easier to drive your rig with constraints to the bvh rig.  Copy location on hip and mainly copy rotation.  Eg add a world copy rotation constraint on  right upper leg to equivalent  bone on other  etc

Comment: I don't remember how to share files here been too long. My brain is full of Blender stuff to memorize already. Basic human T posed character, Carnegie Mellon: Chug Beer.bvh

Comment: Using Blender 2.79

Answer (score 1):

Your biggest issue is, the bvh rig uses ZXY euler rotations, your martha rig is in quaternions.

Here is a script to set martha's pose bones to ZXY eulers.  Select martha in pose mode and run script.

```
import bpy

martha = bpy.context.object
for pb in martha.pose.bones:
    pb.rotation_mode = 'ZXY'
```

or import the bvh file with quaternion rotation.

nextly, you will need to do a better job of renaming martha's bones to match bvh rig.

An alternative approach.  Here is code to add a copy rotation constraint to each bone on martha, to a matching bone on bvh rig.  Note: I imported the bvh file and have a rig from that import named "Beer chug", change name in code to suit name of bvh rig.

It simply looks for bone names in martha that match bvh rig and adds a copy rotation constraint from one to other.

```
import bpy
context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene
rig_to = scene.objects.get("Martha")
rig_bvh = scene.objects.get("Beer chug")
martha = rig_to
# remove action from martha
martha.animation_data.action = None

for bvhpb  in rig_bvh.pose.bones:
    pb = martha.pose.bones.get(bvhpb.name)
    if pb is None:
        print(rig_to.name, " has no bone ", bvhpb.name)
        continue
    c = pb.constraints.get("bvhrot") or pb.constraints.new('COPY_ROTATION')
    c.name = "bvhrot"
    c.target = rig_bvh
    c.subtarget = bvhpb.name
    c.owner_space = c.target_space = 'WORLD'
```

Once you have a "driving rig" set up for a certain mocap, it's simply a matter of importing bvh, changing animation on driver rig and martha will follow.  For CMU for instance each bvh file in subject has the same rig.  In differing subjects the bone naming convention is the same but may have differing proportions (Depending on the actor(s) used I suppose).  This *mainly* only effects locations.

Note also you don't need to have same bone names, just a way of matching bone to bone.  There are some tools in "Motion Capture Tools" addon to do this.

Comment: Haha, you beat me to it :P

Comment: not by much jimi 8^)

Answer (score 0):

From what you described, this sounds like the bones are in the wrong rotation mode. The location probably works for all bones, but only the pelvis is generally translated. All the other motion is usually just rotation.

So how to fix this? Go into `Pose Mode`, and enable the `N` info bar. Under `Transform`, there is a dropdown which lets you specify the rotation mode for this bone. `Quaternion` is the default for bones in blender, and if you want them to use `Euler` keys (probably `XYZ Euler`), you have to manually change that for each bone or use the following script to change it automatically.

```
import bpy
for armature in bpy.data.objects:
    if type(armature.data) == bpy.types.Armature:
        for bone in armature.pose.bones:
            bone.rotation_mode = "XYZ"
```

Paste it into a blender text editor and run with `ALT + P`.

Comment: Animating with Blender was a mistake, I should never even consider using Blender ever again. All BVH turns into garbage nothing follows properly. Waste of time.

Comment: I've gone to the uninstall Blender cliff edge so many times. Answers come difficultly and tutorials can be lacking in proper or outdated advise.

Answer (score 0):

The easier way to get a rig to work with BVH is to make a character in Makehuman.

Ingredients needed:

- MakeHuman app. http://www.makehuman.org/download.php
- MakeHuman Exchange (mhx2) https://bitbucket.org/Diffeomorphic/mhx2-makehuman-exchange/get/016613171fda.zip
- Addon for Blender: All MakeHuman search "make" http://www.makehuman.org/download.php

To add The exporter MHX2 to MakeHuman open the MHX2 zip folder find the folder named "9_export_mhx2" copy it and paste it in C:\Program Files\Makehuman\plugins or wherever you decided to install MakeHuman.

In MakeHuman create a character with a "Game engine" skeleton. You can try to get the character to have the same basic dimensions as the Martha character to reskin later on.

Export as mhx2

In Blender User Preferences > File > Check Autorun Python Scripts. Clear stage from all assets like cameras, lights, etc.

File > Import > MakeHuman (mhx2)

Select the character created in MakeHuman and Select the character in the outliner.

In the MakeWalk tab at the top you'll find a Load And Retarget button click select BVH, then hit the Load and Retarget button in the file window.

If you don't get an error message it is compatible and will work properly. If a bone that bends in the wrong direction use it's mirror bone as a roll value.

Example: Copy right forearm roll value to the left forearm:
[image]